# Tracking what email addresses my SMTP server has sent to

Tags: smtp

Do SMTP servers track the email addresses they've sent to? If so, how do I get the list?

I've got a Facebook app that sends confirmation emails whenever a user successfully registers and adds that user to the database.

The table got accidentally emptied and I'd like to recover who the app has sent the confirmation emails to.

Comment: This is why one does backup copies of the database :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most MTAs have a log file which includes this information, but it is typically not saved for more than a few weeks or months. On Linux look in `/var/log`, on other systems read the MTA's documentation, or add information to your question.